# Hint for solving a definite integral $\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{xdy}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Can anyone provide a hint for solving this definite integral:
$\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{xdy}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Comment: See also: [Calculating $\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{x\cdot dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$ requires unusual substitution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1441935)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint: you may start from $y=x \tan(\theta)$

Comment: Can you show some starting steps please?

Comment: That is the starting step. Try that change of variable you will see that the integral becomes simple.

Comment: I thought you need a hint :-) not a full solution :-)

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't be that lazy :-D. Got the answer btw. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Another way, *in this particular example*, is to rewrite your expression as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}&=\frac{x^2+y^2-y^2}{x(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{x(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}-\frac{y^2}{x(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\\
&=\Bigl(\frac{d}{dy} y\Bigr)\cdot \frac{1}{x(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}+ y\cdot \frac{d}{dy}\frac{1}{x(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}\\
&=\frac{d}{dy}\Bigl(\frac{y}{x(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}\Bigr)
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, you have a simple primitive function that you can put into the fundamental theorem of calculus.