# Calculating $\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{x\cdot dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$ requires unusual substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can someone help me understand how to solve this integral? The official solution says to substitute $y=x\cdot \tan(u)$ and $dy=x\cdot \sec^2(u)du$, but I don't understand how I should know that myself.

Here is the integral:

$$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{x\cdot dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

A step-through solution would be appreciated. I haven't done integrals in a while so it would be helpful if you can explain any particularly complicated steps.

Thank you!!!

Comment: $x$ is constant, did you see it?

Comment: A general hint.  When you see a sum of squares, think of a right triangle so that it becomes an instance of the Pythagorean theorem.  Similarly, when you see a difference of squares.

Comment: See also: [Hint for solving a definite integral $\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{xdy}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318090)

Answer (score 2):

Let us go slowly and consider $$I=\int \frac{x\cdot dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$ in which $x$ is whatever you want (it is a constant for the problem).

So, make a first change of variable $y=z x$, $dy=x dz$. So $$I=\int \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2+x^2 z^2\right)^{3/2}}\,dz=\frac 1x \int \frac {dz}{(1+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

I am sure that you can take from here

Comment: How did you know to use $y=zx$? It doesn't seem inherently clear to me why this choice was made, but the resulting solution makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Joeseph. Always use this when you see homogeneous terms ! How did I know ? Just because I am old and I was given the trick !! Your turn : you must teach it to another one ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici could you please explain? Tricks have logic to them and I would like understand it mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle  I = \int \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dy\;,$$ Here $x$ is Constant.

Here  Denominator is in the form of $(x^2+y^2)$

So we will put $y=x\tan \phi,$ Then $\displaystyle dy = d(x\tan \phi)=x\frac{d}{d\phi}\left[\tan \phi\right]d\phi$

so we get $\displaystyle dy = x\sec^2 \phi d\phi$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{x^2\cdot \sec^2 \phi}{x^3\sec^3 \phi}d\phi\;,$$ Here we put $(1+\tan^2 \phi) = \sec^2 \phi$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}\int \cos \phi d\phi = \frac{\sin \phi}{x}+\mathcal{C}$$

Now above we take $\displaystyle y=x\tan \phi\Rightarrow \tan \phi = \frac{y}{x}$

So Using Right angle $\triangle\;,$ We get $\displaystyle \sin \phi = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

So Integral $$\displaystyle I = \frac{y}{x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$\displaystyle \int_{-a}^{a}\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \left[\frac{y}{x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right]_{-a}^{a} $$

$$\displaystyle = \left[\frac{a}{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right]-\left[-\frac{a}{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right] = \left[\frac{2a}{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right]$$